# get data from session in an aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have class Bean,
then I creat some ob off Bean and add them to a list, then I convert list to an array.
I add this array into a session and use it in a aspx page, but cannot get data from session.

```
public Bean[] listAnswer()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LEHUULOC-PC;Initial Catalog=WebThiTracNghiem;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCauhoi";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        List<Bean> Listbean = new List<Bean>();

        Bean[] result = null;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string macauhoi = (string)dr[0];
            string cauhoi = (string)dr[1];
            string cautraloi = (string)dr[2];
            string traloidung = (string)dr[3];
            //string dokho = (string)dr[4];
            Bean answer = new Bean(macauhoi, cauhoi, cautraloi, traloidung, "");
            Listbean.Add(answer);
            result = new Bean[Listbean.Count];
            result = Listbean.ToArray();
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

======================================

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
Bean[] answer = bean.listAnswer();
Session.Add("ANSWER",(Bean[])answer);
```

======================================

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
this is hocsinh page
    <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <%  

        foreach (var Bean in Session["ANSWER"])
        {
        }
    %>
</div>
</form>
```

but I receive error:  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%  
    Bean[] list = (Bean[])Session["RESULT"];
    if (list != null)
        foreach (var Bean in list)
        {
        }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bean has to be serializable and put it like this into your session:

```
Session.Add("ANSWER",bean);
```

read it like this:

```
var beans = Session["Answer"] as Bean[];
```